# Why does RAND sometimes produce multiple results in a MySQL call?

Tags: mysql

I have table `agent` which includes 13 agent IDs and agent names.

```
agent_id|agent_name|
--------|----------|
       1|Jack      |
       2|Jill      |
       3|Jo        |
...
```

When I run this query...

```
select agent_name from agent where agent_id = (FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * 13 ))
```

...MySQL sometimes returns 0 names and sometimes returns many names. Since `(FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * 13 ))` on its own always seems to return a single, non-zero integer, I would expect to get a single name back, but this is not the case. On testing the above query, the following number of names are returned on each execution;

```
Execution | Total Names Returned
1         | 3
2         | 2
3         | 1
4         | 0
5         | 1
6         | 1
7         | 0
8         | 0
9         | 1
10        | 4
```

Clearly, when one runs...

```
select agent_name from agent where agent_id = 3
```

...the same, single, name is returned each time.

I see that the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) explain that

> RAND() in a WHERE clause is evaluated for every row (when selecting from one table) or combination of rows (when selecting from a multiple-table join). Thus, for optimizer purposes, RAND() is not a constant value and cannot be used for index optimizations

I am not sure why this would mean that a single call would return many rows.

If I add `LIMIT 1`

```
select * from agent a where agent_id = (FLOOR( 1 + RAND() * 13 )) limit 1
```

...then the query sometimes returns `NULL`.

**Questions**

- Why does `RAND` return different numbers of records?
- What is the proper way to return a single random agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation says, it is evaluated for each row. It means, the following:

- MySQL gets all rows
- For each row, executes RAND() and if RAND() == id, return the row

For example

Get all rows

- ID = 1, RAND() = 3, no return
- ID = 2, RAND() = 2, return
- ID = 3, RAND() = 4, no return
- ID = 4, RAND() = 4, return

In this case, you have two results.

If you want to get random agent, maybe better approach would be

```
SELECT * FROM `agent` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That makes more sense! Thanks!

Comment: @JamesGeddes Glad I could clarify this for you. Consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: If I add LIMIT 1 then it sometimes returns 0 rows. How do I ensure it always returns a record?

Comment: Added to main question

Comment: @JamesGeddes There is a proper way to return just one random agent at the end of my answer: `SELECT * FROM `agent` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`
What you are doing is selecting random id (in a wrong way). What the query above does is select all agents, randomize them, and return the first one

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your first query is sometimes returning multiple records because `RAND()` is being evaluted for each record in the query.  If you just want a single random agent, then use:

```
SELECT agent_name
FROM agent
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

To further explain your current observations, the following expression is being evaluated once per each agent record:

```
(FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * 13 ))
```

Imagine that for each record, the above happens, by chance, to equal the `agent_id`.  If so, then your first query would return all 13 records.  By the way, the documentation link you cited basically says this.

Comment: Good solution, thanks for the explanation, very helpful :)